# Why i failed to get DropDownList value on submit event

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 project I failed to get my DropDownList data on edit controller.
My UI syntax is bellow:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.School.SchoolID)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.School.SchoolName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.School.SchoolName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.School.SchoolName)
    </div>
</div>       

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentCLass.ID)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentCLass.ClassName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10"> 
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StudentCLass.ID, @ViewBag.StudentCLassList as SelectList,"Select Class")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentCLass.ID)
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

To fill the DropDownList I use bellow syntax:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
{
    using (DB = new StudentContext())
    {
        var result = DB.Students.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == Id);                
        ViewBag.StudentCLassList = new SelectList(DB.StudentClasses
               .Select(sc => new ViewModelClass 
               { 
                   ID = sc.ID, 
                   ClassName = sc.ClassName 
               }).ToList(), "ID", "ClassName"); 

         return View(StudentInfo(result));
     }
 }
```

After click the submit button I can not get DropDownList value on my controller action.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel.ViewModelStudents student)
{    
    var tempResult = student.StudentCLass.ID;    
    //return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

// return View(student);
    }

Model structure

```
public partial class StudentClass
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public StudentClass()
    {
        Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: show your model classes

Answer (score 2):

MVC Doen't post the DropDown list back to the Controller, You will have to populate dropdown list again in POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel.ViewModelStudents student)
{    
    var tempResult = student.StudentCLass.ID;

ViewBag.StudentCLassList = new SelectList(DB.StudentClasses
               .Select(sc => new ViewModelClass 
               { 
                   ID = sc.ID, 
                   ClassName = sc.ClassName 
               }).ToList(), "ID", "ClassName"); 

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

You could write the Dropdown list code in a function, if you don't want to read this dropdown list from DB evertime you can save it to `Session[]`:

```
    public void PopulateDropDownList(){

var items = Session["MyDropDown"] != null ? (SelectList)Session["MyDropDown"] : null;
if(items ! null) {ViewBag.StudentCLassList; return;}

        items = new SelectList(DB.StudentClasses
                       .Select(sc => new ViewModelClass 
                       { 
                           ID = sc.ID, 
                           ClassName = sc.ClassName 
                       }).ToList(), "ID", "ClassName"); 

Session["MyDropDown"] = ViewBag.StudentCLassList = items;

    }
```

**Note:** If you save the DropDown list in `Session`, you don't have write it to ViewBag, but you can access it directly in View.

And call this method in Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel.ViewModelStudents student)
{    
    var tempResult = student.StudentCLass.ID;

    PopulateDropDownList(); 

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**EDIT**

I don't understand you are saying that you want the DropDown to be selected but you are `Redirecting` to `Index'.

If you do:

```
return View(student);
```

Instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

`return RedirectToAction("Index");` will redirect you to Index page, refreshing your webpage.

**EDIT 2:**

I just noticed you have

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentCLass.ID)
```

MVC is posting the Value from this Hidden Back to the Controller. Try removing this,

The thing is that you have two controls with the same `id`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StudentCLass.ID

AND 

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentCLass.ID)
```

Comment: Dawood Awan,thanks for your reply with valuable information,Please tell me how can i get DropDownList selected item in CONTROLLER if i fill DropDownList again in post event.Thanks for your reply

Comment: see my edit. you are redirecting to Index, so you won't see the Edit Page after Post. if you do return View it should work

Comment: sorry please check my edit. i need to get DropDownList value on post portion like:tempResult ,i need to use this value for some other work,Will you plz tell me how to get DropDownList selected value in POST controller portion.Thanks

Comment: It should be posting back the selected value IF it is inside the HTML.beginform

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel.ViewModelStudents student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         // save changes and redirect

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        using (DB = new StudentContext())
        {
            ViewBag.StudentCLassList = new SelectList(DB.StudentClasses.ToList(), "ID", "ClassName");         
        }

        return View(student);
    }
}
```

The framework will take care of preserving selected values across requests.

Comment: i do the same thing as your syntax ,thanks but problem is in Edit method student i can not my dropDownList information .i can not get the selected value

Comment: there is an overload for new SelectList() that takes 4 parameters (the fourth one being the selected value). it doesn't work if there is more than one selectlist with the same name though